# How to use Strings.xml in ViewModel without using context in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

We have existing app, we need to add Multiple Language Support for that app.
All the strings which are accessed with String.xml are translating.
but we have a constants (which are strings), which we are accessing in VewModel.
these constant are not getting translate.code structure is like below

Constant.kt file

```
    class Constants private constructor() {

companion object {

    const val NAME= "Name"
    const val LAST_NAME= "Last name"
    
}
```

ViewModel looks like this

VewModel.kt

```
 class VewModel() : ViewModel() {
    fun getStrings():String{
        return NAME+LAST_NAME
    }
}
```

In Activity calling method like this

```
viewmodel.getStrings()
```

and there are relevant strings of Name and Last_Name in all multiple Strings.xml file.

I am not getting How do i convert those constant strings to multiple languages.
I cant use context in viewmodel and constants(Architecture restrictions).
any help.

Comment: if you are using databinding you can format/get string in layout ... if you wana do it in viewmodel then you have to use AndroidViewModel as base ... then you have access to Context and obviously with Context you have access to resources ... edit: *I cant use context in viewmodel and constants(Architecture restrictions)* **then you can't acccess resources**

Comment: @Selvin can't use AndroidViewModel  bcz Architecture designed like that .. can u explain about that format/get string in layout

Comment: it is explained in "Layouts and binding expressions" in official guide (Resources section)

Comment: @Selvin i will check .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either you use binding expression in your xml layout, for example the text:

```
android:text="@{@string/name_label + `: ` + viewModel.name}"    //not single quote, be careful
```

Or use `AndroidViewModel`:

```
class StudentViewModel(private val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val name = "Sam"

    fun getNameText() = "${application.getString(R.string.name_label): $name}"
```

---

The way you pass arguement to `ViewModel` is through the `ViewModelFactory`, just boilerplate code:

```
class StudentViewModelFactory(private val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(StudentViewModel::class.java)) {
            return StudentViewModel(application) as T
        }

        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

And setup both in your `fragment`:

```
viewModelFactory = StudentViewModelFactory( requireActivity().application)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(StudentViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: android:text="@{@string/name_label + `: ` + viewModel.name}"   How come this will help.. it will concatenate both fields ... combines name in two languages(for ex.. Japness name and english name)

Comment: @Gaju Kollur I assume that you have known how to do translation in `String.xml` file, then the next question would be, what can be translated and what cannot be translated. For general text like label "Name: ", "Age: ", they can be translated, you should put them in `String.xml`. But for others, like the customer name, or product name, those are normally hard to standardlize the translation, not to mention the dialect. Therefore for those text you need to manually translate, one good way to do it is to provide "seconday name" field for user to enter.